# asp.net core API with POSTMAN works fine but with jquery ajax not work?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

what I want to do is using HttpContext.Session in the API

in the same WebApi Controller but different actions.

```
$.ajax({
url:baseAppUrl+"api/login",
type:"post",
data:{
action:"sms",
username:"",///mobile phone
},
success:function(ret,err){

}
```

it will give me a code and then use the code to login.

but after the ajax send the reqeust again I can not get the HttpContext.Session.

I am using .net core 3.1

```
if (action.Equals("sms"))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                return Json(new { Ok = false, Message = "parameter is null" });
            }
            Random rnd = new Random();
            var verifyCode = rnd.Next(111111, 999999).ToString();
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("code", verifyCode);
            return Json(new { Ok = true, Message = verifyCode });
        }
```

and in the login action:

```
if (action.Equals("mobileLogin"))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
            {
                return Json(new { Ok = false, Message = "paremeter is null" });
            }
            var userCode = HttpContext.Session.GetString("code"); //the userCode will be null.
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userCode))
            {
                ////.....
            }
}
```

but with the postman all is worked.

why?

Comment: Could you post here also the code of the controller action please? Which version of .NET Core are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In `Startup.cs`, make sure the following is added to `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{
    ...  
    services.AddSession(options => {  
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);//You can set Time   
    });
    ...  
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseSession();
    ...
}
```

Please, also check that the browser receives the session cookie. In Chrome:

1. click in the lock icon in URL bar
2. click  Cookies
3. see if there is a cookie `.AspNetCore.Session`, as in the following picture

[image]

If the cookie is there, the problem is probably not in handling session data but somewhere else.

Comment: It is working in developpment but not work in the iis.

Comment: modified the answer

Comment: Could you also please try run the app in a different browser and in the anonymous mode?